# Inline html editing or rewrite the entire line

Tags: php, html, css

Which one is a better practice to write php, I know using a CSS class would be better but this is just an example. Is it better to rewrite the whole line or is it better to edit within the line?

I like the first example, but I feel like it is a bit redundant, the second example is less redundant but harder to read. What practice is the standard for how to do these kinds of manipulations? Is one example executed faster?

```
if(isset($affiliationError) && $affiliationError) 
    echo '<label for="affiliation" style="color: #F66;">Affiliation:</label>';
else
    echo '<label for="affiliation">Affiliation:</label>';

// OR //

echo '<label for="affiliation" ';

if(isset($affiliationError) && $affiliationError)
    echo 'style="color: #F66;" ';

echo '>Affiliation:</label>
```

Comment: Don't optimize prematurely! And I would go for the least redundant choice. What if you want to change your output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the first option will run a hair faster, since you only run one `echo` as opposed to three. Not enough to worry about, though, unless you're running 10,000 of these on a page (in which case you *definitely* need to use a css class!).

I think the best way to deal with this is to set a `$style` variable, then build it into your string, like so:

```
$style = "";
if(isset($affiliationError) && $affiliationError)
    $style = 'style="color: #F66;" ';

echo '<label for="affiliation" '.$style.'>Affiliation:</label>';

// OR

echo "<label for=\"affiliation\" $style>Affiliation:</label>";
```

It's less efficient than either of your options, I suppose, but still plenty fast enough to not worry about.

Comment: I don't think is less efficient. +1 because I would do it like this as well.

Comment: `+1` I like the flow of this better than both my examples! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which code do you find easier to maintain or read? I find the first easier to read (although I prefer `{}` around my if statements).

Another option is inline if (although I'm not sure it is better)

```
echo '<label for="affiliation" '. ((isset($affiliationError) && $affiliationError) ? 'style="color: #F66;" ' : "") . '>Affiliation:</label>'
```

OR (my preference)

```
<label for="affiliation" <?php echo ((isset($affiliationError) && $affiliationError) ? 'style="color: #F66;" ' : "") ?>>Affiliation:</label>
```

I often use the above option with user1618143's enhancement of a $style variable for ease of reading and maintenance. For example

```
$style = (isset($affiliationError) && $affiliationError) ? 'style="color: #F66;" ' : "";
<label for="affiliation" <?php echo $style ?>>Affiliation:</label>
```